# Add current time to database and when reading it later check if that time has passed

Tags: php

So I'd like to add the current time to the database, to a specific user when he does something, and later on read it, and check if that time has passed (by checking current time and substracting that from the one in database; to check if it has passed or not)

So how would I do this? I tried with something like this:

```
$date = date("YmWjis");
$calculate = $date - $info['lastvisit'];
if($calculate <= -1)
{
echo "you need to wait before visiting again"; // (just an example)
} else {
//do something
}
```

I also tried both:

```
!$calculate < 0
$calculate < 0
```

etc. But I can't get it to work. Can anyone help me? :P

edit for Parag;

```
$date = date("YmWjis");
$dote = date("YmWjis") + $time; // ($time is set earlier and is 30 seconds)
echo "wait " . $date = $date - $dote . " seconds until next visit";
```

work?
It says like "wait 20138269786674 seconds until next visit".

Comment: you can do it all with in the db, which one are you using?

Comment: @Dagon What do you mean? :p
MySQL if that's what you're asking.

Anyways, I have already fixed the update stuff etc, but it seems to not be substracting or whatever.

Comment: If you're just wanting to save the time of last visit and compare to time of this visit, consider just storing the time in a PHP session.

Comment: `SELECT .. TIMEDIFF(NOW(),YOUR_DATE_FIELD) ..`

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
$dateDiff = new DateTime("2014-04-27 22:00:15");

$date = new DateTime();
$diff = $date->diff($dateDiff);
if($diff->invert == 0)
{
echo "you need to wait before visiting again"; // (just an example)
} else {
//do something
}
```

Comment: i have tested this answer and it seems to be working I would suggest that he try this

Answer (score 0):

```
$db_time = "2014/04/28 15:15:15";
$cur_time = "2014/04/28 18:15:15";

if(strtotime($cur_time) > strtotime($db_time))
{
     // Current time exceeds DB time
     $diff = date('Y/m/d H:i:s', strtotime($cur_time)-strtotime($db_time));
     echo $diff;
}
else
{
    // Current time didn't exceeds DB time
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
 $date = strtotime(date("YmWjis"));
 $dote = strtotime(date("YmWjis")) + $time; // ($time is set earlier and is 30 seconds)
 echo "wait " . $date = $date - $dote . " seconds until next visit";
```

**DEMO**

http://3v4l.org/LBIXu

Comment: I edited my first post (at the bottom from "edit for Parag) - Could you check that and help with that? :p

Comment: What your output should look like?

Comment: I have a time set in the database each time someone is doing a specific action. (by the date thing I posted) Then I want it to check if that time has passed or not, once the person is trying to do the specific action again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51549/discussion-between-woopwoop-woopwoop-and-parag-tyagi)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a database. This does the job without the db overhead. It uses [PHP sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php).

```
<?php

session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['lastVisitTime'])) {
    $_SESSION['lastVisitTime']=new DateTime();
} else {
    $now=new DateTime();
    if ($_SESSION['lastVisitTime']->diff($now) > $someMaxValueYouDefine) {
        echo "You must wait before visiting again.";
    }
}
```